# Run process with multiprocessing and serve its state with django

Tags: python, django, python-multithreading

I would like to serve a page with django, but I want the contents to evolve over time regardless of whether the page is requested.

My initial plan is to have `views.py` launch a process with multiprocessing, which will loop endlessly and update the content. I suppose it needs to have some shared state with the launching process, so that django can get the content to serve it to clients.

I am posting this question to see if people can find some obvious fault with my approach, or suggest an obviously better one.

Comment: How is this content evolving? Do you just want to have a page that will display updates to the user without reloads? Where is this content coming from?

Comment: The content will be an image, think of it as a canvas, and every few seconds, a shape will be quasi-randomly added to the canvas. We do plan to make it display those changes without a reload in the future, but right now I just want to make the content evolve independelty of requests, and then I'll probably add something like node.js to propagate changes to clients.

Comment: Better make plain python script or Django [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/) and start it independently (for example, with [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/))

Comment: How will I be able to have access to this independent process' state, so that I can serve it, though?